# Error:#200 The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Facebook Login URL Code :**

```
$this->set("facebookUrl",$this->facebook->getLoginUrl(
                array(
                        'scope' => 'email,publish_actions',
                        'redirect_uri' =>"http://redirected_url"
                        'display'=>"popup"
                )
        ));
```

**Post story on facebook code :**

```
$params = array(
                "access_token" => "access_token_of_logged_in_user", 
                "message" => "Testing facebook post",
                "picture" => "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Og6yH.jpg?s=128&g=1",
                "caption" => "www.pontikis.net",
                "description" => "Description of post."
                    );

$myProfile  =   $this->facebook->api('/me');
$permissions = $this->facebook->api('/me/permissions');
pr($permissions);
try {
    $ret = $this->facebook->api('/'.$myProfile['id'].'/feed', 'POST', $params);
    echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
    } 
catch(Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Permission Displayed here :**

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [permission] => public_profile
                    [status] => granted
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [permission] => email
                    [status] => granted
                )

        )

)
```

**I got following Error when I post on facebook :**

```
(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

Comment: When a user enter your fb application which "permission" he gotta accept? =)

Comment: Yes, he accept permission after that he post on facebook then he got above error.

Comment: have you searched on fb developer site?

Comment: Yes! but no luck to find this problem.

Comment: won't you need on "permission displayed here" a post grant? i do not see it

Comment: Developer site said to add `publish_actions` instead of `public_stream` but not working

Comment: @MarcoMura Have you any suggestion or solution to resolving this error?

Comment: are you trying with a user who is app admin or developer?

Comment: btw, publish_stream is deprecated since years. not sure where you guys keep copying code from...

Comment: also, you are using the old php sdk. still works, but is not recommended.

Comment: @luschn Yes I treid with admin or developer it successfully posted.

Comment: then tobis answer is correct

Comment: Let me check Tobi answer and If correct then I accept it

Comment: @luschn  Can you help me how to pass `Login Review`?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Graph API >=v2.0, then you need to pass Login Review for non admin/tester/developer users before you can use this permission in your app:

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review

Comment: not sure how they keep missing the clearly visible warning about that when authorizing the app with an app developer...

Comment: @Tobi Can you help me how to pass `Login Review`?

Comment: I don't work for Facebook, so no... While you're developping you should be able to grant all the permissions as described in my answer. You just can't use other users than admins/testers/develoeprs